# Find a third circles that crosses two other circles at an angle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry

Given two circles at positions $P_0$ and $P_1$ of radius $R_0$ and $R_1$, respectively, is it possible to find the position $P$ and radius $R$ of a third circle that intersects a point $P_2$ and crosses through the other circles at an angle $\theta$?

[See Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjpzD.png)